# Admin-ajax.php appending a status code to ajax response

Tags: plugin-development, php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a plugin that uses Ajax (jQuery with form plugin) via a form submission and the php function returns a JSON response.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_bubbly-upload', 'bubbly_upload_submit' );

function bubbly_upload_submit() {
    // generate the response
    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
}
```

In Firefox, none of the jQuery response handlers were firing and the save file dialog was opening with the JSON response. I wouldn't have the issue if I returned HTML. However, in either case, a '0' was appended on to the end of my response. After some digging, it looks like jQuery will not trigger a handler if the JSON reponse is invalid. This '0' being added onto the end is causing the JSON to be invalid.

If I look into the `admin-ajax.php` code, I see this:

```
default :
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_POST['action'] );
    die('0');
    break;
endswitch;
```

The [php docs for die](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) say that if the parameter passed is a string, then it will be printed just before exiting, if it is an integer, it will not be printed.

Without hacking the core, is there a way I can avoid this issue and still use JSON? Also, is this a bug, because I don't see how adding a zero to the end of every AJAX response would be desired...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `die();` in your function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_bubbly-upload', 'bubbly_upload_submit' );

function bubbly_upload_submit() {
    // generate the response
    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
    die();
}
```

Reference: [WordPress Codex, AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks! I should have read the codex more carefully... I've been looking at that page for days now.

Comment: You are welcome!... When you keep visiting the codex every day, you will eventually memorize plenty of pages urls like this one. :)